# model theory & algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

recently I'm taking mathematical logic course, and the class covers some basic model theoretical ideas. Since I have not taken any abstract algebra course, It is so hard to understand what is going on.

proving ACFp is not $w$-cateogircal, professor defined $F_n=Q(\alpha_i |i<n)$ where $\alpha_i$ is transcendental and algebraically independent. he just wrote "if $m\neq n$, then $F_n\ncong F_m$, but $F_n, F_m \models T_{ACF_0}$" where $T_{ACF_0}$ is a set of axioms of algebraically closed field of characteristic 0.
 I don't get what is $Q(\alpha_i |i<n)$, so do $F_n\ncong F_m$, and $F_n, F_m \models T_{ACF_0}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I'll change

Comment: Feel free to ask your other questions, so long as they are one per each thread.

Comment: The instructor may not have said exactly that. We add $n$ algebraically independent transcendentals *and then* take the algebraic closure.